# Get mapped field with partial select in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a post entity which may represent the Post or Comment to another post.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="comments")
 */
private $post;
public function setPost($post) { $this->post = $post; return $this; }
public function getPost() { return $this->post; }

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="post", cascade={"remove"})
 */
private $comments;
public function getComments() { return $this->comments; }
....
```

So normally i can get parent Post by `->getPost();`.

Now i want to optimize request and using partial select like this one

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
->createQuery(
    "SELECT partial post.{id, title, Post}
    FROM XXXMyBundle:Post post
    ORDER BY post.id ASC
    ")
```

But each time i see errors like

> There is no mapped field named 'Post' on class

I tried to change field name in query to **post_id**, **post** or **postId** but it didn't help.

Is there any way to get the post_id (that's name of the field in database) ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844970/no-mapped-field-when-using-partial-query-and-composite-keys-in-doctrine2) i solved my problem.

```
"SELECT partial post.{id, title}, partial p.{id}
             FROM XXXMyBundle:Post post
             LEFT JOIN post.post p
             ORDER BY post.id ASC
```